# CakePHP title_for_layout

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this function:

```
function view ( $id )
{
    $this->layout = 'page';

    $this->User->id = $id;

    $this->set('title_for_layout', $username);

    $this->set('users', $this->User->read());
}
```

What I want to do is show the username as the title but the current code I have doesn't do this... how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->User->id = $id;
$this->set('title_for_layout', $this->User->field('username'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function view ( $id )
{
$this->layout = 'page';

$this->User->id = $id;

$this->set('title_for_layout',  $this->User->field('username'));

$this->set('users', $this->User->read());
}
```